# LPLinkView Hide Info View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, preview

I am working on project with different files (video, photo, links) so we are going to use LPLinkView to present it directly from url like following image

[image]

So please if there is anyway to hide the footer view that include metadata (title, text, url) and only keep the preview?

If not can't you suggest me any library that do what we want?

Looking to here from your side

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't manage any internal properties of a LPLinkView, but you can use `LPLinkMetadata` instead and extract the images from its `imageProvider`.

So, you can create your own function to get the image from the imageProvider

```swift
import LinkPresentation
import UIKit

func getImageFromMetadata(url: URL, completion:  @escaping  (UIImage)-> Void) {
    LPMetadataProvider().startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (linkMetadata, error) in
        guard let linkMetadata = linkMetadata, let imageProvider = linkMetadata.imageProvider else { return }
        imageProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (image, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("provider error")
                return
            }

            if let image = image as? UIImage {
                // now you can do whatever you want with the image. 
                // for we now are going to send it to the completion handler
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(image)
                }
            } else {
                print("image not found")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the function to load the image to your UIImageView

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YyeaaDOWho") else { return }

getImageFromMetadata(url: url) { image in
    imageView.image = image
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is working with imges but what about videos, files, audios?